# How can we create a graph of Dagger 2's dependencies?

Tags: java, android, graph, dagger-2, dagger

How can I generate a visual graph with all the dependencies Dagger 2 manages?

Guice has [Grapher](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Grapher). Does anyone know how to do something similar in Dagger 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything ready yet.

There's an [open issue in Dagger 2 Github](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/288) requesting the same.

Comment: I see, it is still in progress https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/287

Answer (score 5):

I have built [Scabbard](https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/scabbard) using [Dagger SPI](https://dagger.dev/spi.html) that can generate Dagger 2 dependency graph during build time and later it link to `@Component` and `@Subcomponent` in IDE via IDE plugins.

Example:

[image: Dagger 2 graph preview]